# Trigger change event on document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to re-calculate everything not only on change, but also when the page loads.

i tried the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //trigger misc costs

        $("input[class~='miscc']").trigger('change');
        $("input[class~='misch']").trigger('change');


//other events here....

    //add up repeater miscaleneous mnumbers
    //dollar amoungs
    $("input[class~='miscc']").change(function (event) {
        //only allow numbers
        this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');

        var sum = 0;
        var num = 0;
        $("input[class~='miscc']").each(function (event) {
            num = parseFloat($(this).val()) || 0;
            sum = sum + num;
        });
        $("input[id*='txtMiscC']").val(sum.toFixed(2));
        $("input[class~='cost']").trigger('change');
    });

    //hours
    $("input[class~='misch']").change(function (event) {
        //only allow numbers
        this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');

        var sum = 0.00;
        var num = 0;
        $("input[class~='misch']").each(function (event) {
            num = parseFloat($(this).val()) || 0;
            sum = sum + num;
        });
        $("input[id*='txtMiscH']").val(sum.toFixed(1));
        $("input[class~='hours']").trigger('change');
    });
});
```

but nothing is happening, am i doing it wrong?

Answer (score 6):

You are triggering the event before you bind the event handler. First bind the handler, then trigger the event.

Answer (score 0):

Add change events to the bottom.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

//other events here....

    //add up repeater miscaleneous mnumbers
    //dollar amoungs
    $("input[class~='miscc']").change(function (event) {
        //only allow numbers
        this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');

        var sum = 0;
        var num = 0;
        $("input[class~='miscc']").each(function (event) {
            num = parseFloat($(this).val()) || 0;
            sum = sum + num;
        });
        $("input[id*='txtMiscC']").val(sum.toFixed(2));
        $("input[class~='cost']").trigger('change');
    });

    //hours
    $("input[class~='misch']").change(function (event) {
        //only allow numbers
        this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');

        var sum = 0.00;
        var num = 0;
        $("input[class~='misch']").each(function (event) {
            num = parseFloat($(this).val()) || 0;
            sum = sum + num;
        });
        $("input[id*='txtMiscH']").val(sum.toFixed(1));
        $("input[class~='hours']").trigger('change');
    });

    //trigger misc costs

        $("input[class~='miscc']").trigger('change');
        $("input[class~='misch']").trigger('change');
});
```